# How to build/install gtk-sharp 3.0 on windows?

Tags: build, gtk#

I need to build/install gtk-sharp 3.0 on windows from https://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp . How can i do it? Can you give me some instructions?

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @JacobSánchez hi, sorry, it was long time ago, I think I ended up using C and GTK for C for my needs instead of C# and gtk for C#